# Hat chasing : How old is old?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2015

For the *Living In The Future* and the *Timey Wimey* hats, it is required to answer/edit an **old** post. But "old" is pretty subjective.

So what time span defines "old" in this case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the extended hat descriptions on the Winter Bash page:

> Timey Wimey: edit 5 questions that were posted more than a year earlier
>
> Living in the Future: self-answer a question you asked before Winter Bash and score +5 on the answer

Comment: Oh, well that was easy.